# lme4: How to specify random slopes while constraining all correlations to 0?

Tags: r, lme4

Due to an interesting turn of events, I'm trying use the `lme4` package in R to fit a model in which the random slopes are not allowed to correlate with each other *or* the random intercept. Effectively, I want to estimate the variance parameter for each random slope, but none of the correlations/covariances. From the reading I've done so far, I think what I want is effectively a diagonal variance/covariance structure for the random effects.

An answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35401176/18049168) provides a workaround to specify a model where slopes are correlated with intercepts, but not with each other. <s>I also know the `||` syntax in `lme4` makes slopes that are correlated with each other, but not with the intercepts.</s>  Neither of these seems to fully accomplish what I'm looking to do.

Borrowing the example from the [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399127/lme4-how-to-specify-2-correlations-with-random-intercept-without-adding-correl), if my model is:

`m1 <- lmer (Y ~ A + B + (1+A+B|Subject), data=mydata)`

is there a way to specify the model such that I estimate variance parameters for A and B while constraining *all three* correlations to 0? I would like to achieve a result that looks something like this:

```
VarCorr(m1)    
##  Groups   Name        Std.Dev. Corr       
##  Subject  (Intercept) 1.41450             
##           A           1.49374  0.000      
##           B           2.47895  0.000 0.000
##  Residual             0.96617
```

I'd prefer a solution that could achieve this for an arbitrary number of random slopes. For example, if I were to add a random effect for a third variable C, there would be 6 correlation parameters to fix at 0 rather than 3. However, anything that could get me started in the right direction would be extremely helpful.

### Edit:

On asking this question, I misunderstood what the `||` syntax does in `lme4`. Struck through the incorrect statement above to avoid misleading anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *exactly* what the double-bar notation does. *However*, note that the `||` in `lme4` does **not work as one might expect for factor variables**. It does work 'properly' in `glmmTMB`, and the `afex::mixed()` function is a wrapper for `[g]lmer` which *does* implement a fully functional version of `||`. (I have meant to import this into `lme4` for years but just haven't gotten around to it yet ...)

### simulated example

```r
library(lme4)
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(A = runif(500), B = runif(500), 
                 Subject = factor(rep(1:25, 20)))
dd$Y <- simulate(~ A + B + (1 +  A + B|Subject), 
  newdata = dd,
  family = gaussian,
  newparams = list(beta = rep(1,3), theta = rep(1,6), sigma = 1))[[1]]
```

### solution

```r
summary(m <- lmer (Y ~ A + B + (1+A+B||Subject), data=dd))
```

The correlations aren't listed because they are structurally absent (internally, the random effects term is expanded to `(1|Subject) + (0 + A|Subject) + (0+B|Subject)`, which is also why the groups are listed as `Subject`, `Subject.1`, `Subject.2`).

```r
Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject   (Intercept) 0.8744   0.9351  
 Subject.1 A           2.0016   1.4148  
 Subject.2 B           2.8718   1.6946  
 Residual              0.9456   0.9724  
Number of obs: 500, groups:  Subject, 25
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I misunderstood what the || syntax does. For anyone else facing a similar problem, I think what slipped me up was that my A and B were dummy variables encoded as factors, so using the || syntax calculated a variance parameter for each level and the correlation between those variances. Changing the predictors back to numeric dummy variables gets me the result I was looking for.